# wrong edit made by a user

Tags: discussion, editing, on-hold-questions

I have asked [Homotopy invariance of de Rham cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643279/homotopy-invariance-of-de-rham-cohomology)  question

Some user has changed the context from homotopy invariant(by which I mean homotopy equivalent) to diffeomorphic. This is totally different things. And that same user has answered question assuming it is diffeomorphic. I was really upset with this behaviour. I have rolled back his edit. Then there was a confusion regarding my wording homotopy invariant and I said in comments and even in the edit that I mean homotopy equivalent manifolds.

And now the question is on hold.

Instead of notifying user who has made wrong edit, my question is now put on hold.

How can some one not aware of the context can edit the question. I have seen people who have closed this question as unclear, except one user, I do not see if other users has contributed anything for questions with this concept or this tags differential geometry/algebraic topology/homotopy theory/deRham cohomology. How can they decide if this is not clear?

I guess it is better to keep some criterion on contribution to specific amount to vote to close or open a question of that particular tag which is not very basic tag. Tags which are not basic for example linear algebra, calculus, elementary number theory has to be such that any edit made to questions has to be done by users who has contributed enough.

Edit : 22 upvotes and 3 downvotes for this post as of now. I don’t understand why this is getting so much attention :D... There is no answer/discussion regarding **minimum contribution criterion to edit a question**..

Comment: Do you want to ask (1) Why is my question unclear?, or (2) what should be done for users making wrong edit? or (3) suggesting some minimal requirement to be satisfied in order to vote in those subjects?

Comment: @JohnMa why is my question unclear does not suit here I guess, I have asked in comments to that question. I only mentioned it here, I am asking questions 2 and 3

Comment: For (2) probably nothing can be done if it is just one instance. But if you find out some users trying to invalidate others post by editing, you can flag those post and report to the moderators (choosing "in need of moderators attention). They have the power to deal with it (for example, suspending the user)

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me what you were thinking when putting my question on hold!? @JohnMa

Comment: (3) I personally always thought that at least can be discussed. The requirement could be low - just to prove that the voters are interested in that field. I am not sure if it is feasible for some "more advanced" tag though, since participation is already low. It could also mean that the fate of those questions are controlled by a small group of people.

Comment: Concerning why it is unclear: The proof is long, and you did not tell us where do you not understand. Indeed Kevin gave an answer, only to find out that you are asking another questions.

Comment: To me, Kevin's answre completely solved the problem.

Comment: I think that the best thing to do about a wrong edit is to politely point out the misunderstanding and re-edit or rollback. Everybody makes mistakes.

Comment: For point (2) above, let me make that clear: flagging is suggested only if it is NOT an isolated issue.

Comment: @ArnaudD. You are right, I should have dealt this more politely.

Comment: More politely how, or are there deleted comments that I didn't see?  Your level of politeness seems fine; it's [another's level that isn't](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643279/homotopy-invariance-of-de-rham-cohomology#comment5459072_2643279).

Comment: I am sorry to interrupt, but how come a question on de Rham cohomology is asked on Mathematics and not on MathOverflow?

Comment: @tilper I flagged that comment.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy, appreciate the vigilance but I wouldn't expect much to come of it since I've seen worse from higher rep users on this site.

Comment: @mike239x, MO is for research-level questions.  While de Rham cohomology is a somewhat relatively advanced topic, the question itself was not research level.  Also, sometimes the line isn't so clear and a post may be valid on both sites.  Sometimes it's subjective.

Comment: @mike239x (1) deRham cohomology can be introduced once we know advanced calculus (Indeed I know some universities where this is introduced in Honour calculus 4). (2) Anything that is on topic in MO is by (more or less by definition) on topic here at MSE.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy I do not quite remember what comment you have tagged.. Did I write that comment? Can you tell me if you remember

Comment: @tilper To be frank, I do not even remember what I have written in that comments and now that comments are not there. you can check title of this post it was "action" on wrong edit made by a user. By politely I mean I should not have said that "action" thing. I have edited that now.

Comment: @JohnMa I would not quite agree that deRham cohomology can be introduced once we know advanced calculus. You can give the definition but I doubt that you can do anything more than that...

Comment: @mike239x I second tilper in reply to your comment. It is advanced but not of research level...

Comment: @cello : [This book](https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Cohomology-Rham-Characteristic-Classes/dp/0521589568) is exactly trying to do that, and this is where I started learning deRham cohomology when I was an undergraduate. Extremely painful but is doable.

Comment: @JohnMa When I say you can not do more, I was having in mind deRham cohomology of smooth manifolds and deRham theorem relating singular cohomology and deRham cohomology.. You can definitely do but it  just about the pain you are ready to take. No offense :) :)

Comment: 22 upvotes and 3 downvotes for this.. ?? I don’t understand why this is getting so much attention :D... there was no answer for what I asked though.. regarding minimum contribution criterion to edit a question..

Comment: I've had this happen before. A user suggested a very wrong edit to my answer and someone approved it for some reason. I just rolled it back and left a slightly passive aggressive comment on my answer for it. Haha.